# Hover, click, and release sounds not working. I'm confused

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I'm trying out new things for my website which involve when I hover, click or release a link I interact with it should play a sound. I am still getting used to the basics of HTML, sorry if I seem confused but I thought this would have been the right direction.

This is what I have so far:

```
<html>
  <audio id="myaudio" src="hover"></audio>
  <audio id="myaudio2" src="click"></audio>
  <audio id="myaudio3" src="release"></audio>
  <body>
    <a href="https://google.com"
       onmouseover="document.getElementById('myaudio').play()"
       onmousedown="document.getElementById('myaudio2').play()"
       onmouseup="document.getElementById('myaudio3').play()">google.com</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The `src` attributes for `<audio>` elements do not appear to be `audio/*` files? `javascript` at Question should return expected result where `src` points to URL of audio file

Comment: Thank you, I see now where I messed up. I forgot that src needs to point to a link instead of a name. Thank you very much!

Comment: _"and play normal too. I'm just lost with this because I have not worked with audio like this yet."_ Where are you lost? `javascript` at Question returns expected results, yes?

Comment: I didn't see your full comment when I replied the first time, but again thank you.

Answer (score 1):

@guest271314 helped me with this one, turns out it was really easy.
I forgot that the SRC tag needs to point to a link. Here is the correction:

```
<html>
<audio id="myaudio" src="http://yourdomain.com/hover.wav"></audio>
<audio id="myaudio2" src="http://yourdomain.com/click.wav"></audio>
<audio id="myaudio3" src="http://yourdomain.com/release.wav"></audio>
<body>
<a href="https://google.com" onmouseover="document.getElementById('myaudio').play()" onmousedown="document.getElementById('myaudio2').play()" onmouseup="document.getElementById('myaudio3').play()">google.com</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the part fixed:

```
src="http://yourdomain.com/sound.wav"
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to make your web page plays music, the html code can be as simple as

```
<audio id="myaudio" src="c.mp3" controls></audio>
```